# C# - Why doesn't time and date save in mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have the following code:

```
private void saveDT()
    {

        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(Common.myConnection);
        myConn.Open();
        string sLastLogin = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE ha_system.tblaccounts SET lastlogin='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "' WHERE name='" + Common.ActiveUser + "'", myConn);
        try
        {
            mySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fehler: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

But time and date is only saved after the second login in the database column "lastlogin".
Why? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The first thing to do is to use parameterized SQL instead of converting your values into strings and including them directly in the SQL. That may well solve your issue anyway - so fix that first. That will close a SQL injection attack hole at the same time...

Comment: And also you need to show us more code, the update seems fine apart from parametrization

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have provided us besides the SQL being un-parameterized and the disposable objects not being disposed.

Comment: Your conversion of C# DateTime to MySQL format should be: `string sLastLogin = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 1):

beside the other comments about avoiding SQL injection, you do not need to get a DateTime value from .NET into the MySQL server, you can use built in function and have a query like this:

```
"UPDATE ha_system.tblaccounts SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write the datetime literal in a valid format, it should work fine.

dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss is not a valid format for a MySQL datetime literal.  It's also ambiguous, at any rate.  Try yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, with the appropriate capitalization of H and M in the right places for the function you're using.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

And, seriously, don't build queries by concatenating strings.

Comment: Excellent and perfectly valid point, but is this the reason they are seeing the database write only after the second login? I'm not convinced. BTW I added a comment to the question with the C# syntax they ought to use.

Comment: @DerekW that's a good question, because the code, as written, should actually never work... the incorrect formatting should try, but fail, on the MySQL side, to implicitly cast to a datetime, with the resulting value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' being written to the table.

Comment: That sounds pretty accurate to me, but why are they sometimes having success (ie. the second login). I'm thinking this is a case of incomplete code.